# Pika connection closed after 3 heartbeats

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I'm writing a script which receives HTTP requests (using Tornado), parses them, and sends them to a RabbitMQ broker using pika.

The code looks like this:

```
def main():
    conn_params = pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host=BROKER_NAME,
        port=BROKER_PORT,
        ssl=True,
        virtual_host=VIRTUAL_HOST,
        credentials=pika.PlainCredentials(BROKER_USER, BROKER_PASS),
        heartbeat_interval=HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL
    )
    conn = pika.BlockingConnection(conn_params)
    channel = conn.channel()

    # Create the web server which handles application requests.
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (URL_BILLING, SomeHandler, dict(channel=channel))
    ])

    # Start the server
    application.listen(LISTENING_PORT)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

As you can see, I open a single connection and channel, and pass the channel to any instance of the handler which is created, the idea being to save traffic and avoid opening a new connection/channel for every request.

The issue I'm experiencing is that the connection is closed after **3 heartbeats**. I used Wireshark in order to figure out what the problem is, but all I can see is that the server sends a PSH (I'm assuming this is the heartbeat) and my scripts replies with an ACK. This happens 3 times with HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL in between them, and then the server just sends a FIN and the connection dies.

Any idea why that happens? Also, should I keep the connection open or is it better to create a new one for every message I need to send?

Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE:** I looked in the RabbitMQ log, and it says:
`Missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 10s`
I thought the server was meant to send heartbeats to the client, to make sure it answers, and this agrees with what I observed using Wireshark, but from this log it seems it is the client which is meant to report to the server, not the other way around, and the client, evidently, doesn't report. Am I getting this right?

**UPDATE:** Figured it out, sort of. A blocking connection (which is what I used) is unable to send heartbeats because it's, well, blocking. As mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/636), the `heartbeat_interval` parameters is only used to negotiate the connection with the server, but the client doesn't actually send heartbeats. Since this is the case, what is the best way to keep a long-running connection with pika? Even if I don't specify `heartbeat_interval`, the server defaults to a heartbeat every 10 minutes, so the connection will die after 30 minutes...

Answer (score 4):

For future visitors:

Pika has an async example which uses heartbeat:
http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/0.10.0/examples/asynchronous_publisher_example.html

For Tornado specific, this example shows how to use Tornado's IOLoop in pika's async model:
http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/0.10.0/examples/tornado_consumer.html